# Jython project in Eclipse can't find the xml module, but works in an identical project

Tags: java, python, eclipse, jython, pydev

I have two projects in Eclipse with Java and Python code, using Jython. Also I'm using PyDev. One project can import and use the xml module just fine, and the other gives the error `ImportError: No module named xml`. As far as I can tell, all the project properties are set identically. The working project was created from scratch and the other comes from code checked out of an svn repository and put into a new project.

What could be the difference?

edit- Same for `os`, btw. It's just missing some path somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

eclipse stores project data in files like

- .project
- .pydevprojct
- .classpath

with checkin / checkout via svn it is possible to lost some of these files

check your dot-files